# Why does Maple include x in the solution of this definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, maple

I have the following function defined in Maple:
$$
f(x) := (2 - a + ax^2) \sqrt{1 + 4a^2x^2}
$$
And I want to calculate the definite integral of this from -1 to 1:
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}{f(x)dx}
$$
I do that by writing the command:

```
> int(f(x), x=-1..1)
```

However, Maple returns a result that contains the variable $x$:
$$
-(1/4)*(-4*sqrt(4*a^2+1)*ax^2*a*csgn(a)+4*sqrt(4*a^2+1)*a^2*csgn(a)-8*sqrt(4*a^2+1)*a*csgn(a)+ln((sqrt(4*a^2+1)*csgn(a)-2*a)*csgn(a))*ax^2-ln((sqrt(4*a^2+1)*csgn(a)+2*a)*csgn(a))*ax^2-ln((sqrt(4*a^2+1)*csgn(a)-2*a)*csgn(a))*a+ln((sqrt(4*a^2+1)*csgn(a)+2*a)*csgn(a))*a+2*ln((sqrt(4*a^2+1)*csgn(a)-2*a)*csgn(a))-2*ln((sqrt(4*a^2+1)*csgn(a)+2*a)*csgn(a)))*csgn(a)/a
$$

Did I do something wrong?
This is my first time using Maple.

Comment: I assume, but really do not know, that Maple does not understand $ax^2$ as "$a$ times $x^2$" but rather as $ax$ squared, where $ax$ is taken as a name of a variable different to $x$ and $a$. Write $a * x^2$ instead and see what happens. (Maybe leaving a space would also suffice, but I'd test with explicit multiplication operator first.)

Comment: The output seems to be version dependent. Further: the `csgn` indicates that Maple treats $a$ as complex. If your $a$ is real you should tell it with 
`assume(a, real);` or even `assume(a>0);`

Comment: thanks for both of you. But @quid's suggestion is actually correct. A space between a and x is suffice.

Comment: It's a good thing to remember that computer programs can't read minds (yet)

Comment: Also, have you defined the function correctly? You define the name of the function and the input variable separately. This always trips my classmates up. You would have          f := x -> ...      where the ... represents your function. (Apologies for the poor formatting, I'm writing this on my phone).

Comment: @YuriyS That's definitely a useful thing to put in mind. Thanks for the tip :). But as I said, this is my first time using Maple and I didn't know that the language allows multi-character variable names for example. If I am to write the parser for such a language, at least a warning is easily detectable in that case since the function is defined on a variable named x and the exact variable name is the suffix of another token which is how people naturally write math and this is a DSL for math, so ...

Comment: This is a great example of why it is important to paste code in verbatim when asking a question - mistypes can be caught this way.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably from a mistake you have in typing when you are defining your function $f(x)$ in Maple. I defined $f(x)$ with the expression in your question (without telling Maple to assume anything about $a$ such as being real or positive etc) and then asked `int(f(x),x=-1..1)`. There is no `x` appearing in the output.

I also can see in your comments that you say putting space between symbols is enough, I am not agree with that, if there is a multiplication between them, then you are better to type `*`. Try to follow the 1-D math input typing habits of Maple as far as you can even when you chose the 2-D math input representation in your Maple worksheet.

[image]